# JsonIgnore on subattributes

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a pretty simple question :

```
class B {
  String c;
  String d;
}

class A {
  B myclass;
}
```

I want to ignore attribute "c" of class "B", but from my "A" class. How can I do something like @JsonIgnoreProperty("myclass.c") ? In no case I want to modify or add an annotation on class "B".

Thank you !

Comment: _In no case I want to modify or add an annotation on class "B"_ Is this because there are other cases where `B.c` has to be serialized or is it just because you don't have control of `B`'s source code?

Comment: Yes, it's because in some cases I need to serialize B fully and in others I want to serialize only specific fields. That being said, it's in the same webservice call so I think JsonViews can't be the solution.

Comment: Specify [`@JsonSerialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html) and you can do whatever you want.